# How can I hinde/unhide rows between cells with bold font vba

Tags: vba, excel, show-hide

I have a list of data (text) that is sorted with bold headlines like the example below. I am looking for a way to hide/unhide rows under the headline, if possible by clicking on the cell.

```
**Headline 1**
Test 
Test 
Test 
**Headline 2** 
Test 
Test 
**Headline 3**
Test 
Test 
Test
```

Started of with this, but can't find a way to make it work (I'm new to VBA)

```
Sub SortBold()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim OutRng As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WorkRng = Sheets("Saftey functions").Range("A3:A20")
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Rng.Font.Bold Then
            If OutRng Is Nothing Then
                Set OutRng = Rng
            Else
                Set OutRng = Union(OutRng, Rng)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not OutRng Is Nothing Then
       OutRng.Select
    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(OutRng)
    If Not OutRng(i) Is Nothing And Not OutRng(i + 1) Is Nothing Then _
        Rows(OutRng(i).Row & ":" & OutRng(i + 1)).Hidden = _
            Not Rows(OutRng(i).Row & ":" & OutRng(i + 1)).Hidden
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your worksheet really called **Saftey** functions ?

Comment: There is a similar answer here: [VBA code to hide or unhide rows based on a cell value](https://superuser.com/a/663446/774713), and several others, this is a pretty common question. Also, see the documentation for the [`Hidden` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-hidden-property-excel) including the example `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("C").Hidden = True`

Comment: Jeeped - Yes, the worksheet is called Saftey functions

Comment: @ashleedawg, I've tried to search for an easy awnser but since the data changes I can not use code including specific row numbers, the number of rows that I want to hide changes as well so I can not pre define to hide, lets say, five rows. But thank you for commenting so fast!

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is getting of `On Error Resume Next`.  You're telling Excel you don't care about any errors (which can cause bigger issues).  Also, I see your sub is called `sortBold`, which prompts me to point out -- many users don't realize that you can Sort by formatting with the regular built-in Sort function, if that could be any help...

Comment: Actually if you just need to hide/unhide the columns between each "section", you could use the built-in Grouping (aka: Outline) functionality. See this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff   If that still isn't what you need then I am out of guesses for what you're trying to do, and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: @ashleedawg I've used the outline function before, and maybe that's the easiest way to do it, but I was hoping to find a way with vba so that I don't have to manually create groups for the new data. 

I was trying  to create something like this:
1. Loop to find all headlines (with bold font) 
2. Save the headlines in an array
3. Hide rows between the headlines using the array as reference
4. If possible make this happen when the user clicks on the cell containing a headline in the excel sheet. 

I got stuck trying to use the array containing headlines as reference to hide rows

Comment: You could probably use outlines, **and** set them up with VBA. With stuff like that I would record a macro of myself creating and removing a couple groups manually, and then look at the code the Recorder generated to figure out the key lines and adjust/autonate from there. If you were to do that and post your code here I (or someone) will likely be able to help you connect the dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by double-clicking anywhere on a row containing bold font in column A.

Put this in your worksheet's private code sheet (right-click worksheet name tab, View Code).

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print Target.Address(0, 0)
    If Cells(Target.Row, "A").Font.Bold Then
        Cancel = True
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rs As Long, re As Long, rng As Range
        rs = Target.Row + 1
        Application.FindFormat.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(Target.Row, "A"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                             LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                             SearchFormat:=True)
        If rng.Row < rs Then
            re = Application.Match("zzz", Columns(1)) + 1
        Else
            re = rng.Row
        End If
        Cells(rs, "A").Resize(re - rs, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = Not Cells(rs, "A").EntireRow.Hidden
    End If
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Works perfectly!